# github pages 404 jekyll sub pages

Tags: github, jekyll

Sub pages fail to generate on GitHub, I get 404 errors, when I try to do the same on localhost:4000 it works.

Website Structure:

```
index.md
-us (folder)
--index.md
--test.md
-uk (folder)
--index.md
--test.md
```

On local it generates:

- www.test.com/index.html
- www.test.com/us/index.html
- www.test.com/us/test/index.html
- www.test.com/uk/index.html
- www.test.com/uk/test/index.html

GitHub generates:

- www.test.com/index.html
- www.test.com/us/index.html
- www.test.com/us/test/index.html - 404
- www.test.com/uk/index.html
- www.test.com/uk/test/index.html - 404

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If your site is in a project repository, his url is like `username.github.io/repositoryName`.

In `_config.yml` add `baseurl: /repositoryName`.

And set your link like this : `[Link text]({{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }})`.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this issue.

For some reason Github pages didn't like my initial structure,
Every subpage should be inside of it's own folder: www.test.com/us/test/index.md 
I had to change website structure to it to:

- www.test.com/index.md
- www.test.com/us/index.md
- www.test.com/us/test/index.md
- www.test.com/uk/index.md
- www.test.com/uk/test/index.md
- www.URL.com/index.md - main index page.
- www.URL.com/subfolder/index.md - subfolder
- www.URL.com/subfolder/subfolder/index.md - 2nd subfolder